# How to remove leading zeros with long string

Tags: java, regex, string, number-formatting

I'm trying to remove leading zeros from a string where there are multiple other strings and numbers in java

```
so ow -   00250 =     00000000 ]
```

for the above input I'm trying to get the output to be

```
so ow - 250 = 0 ]
```

I have tried

```
removeLeadingZeros(str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ")
```

where removeLeadingZeros is

```
    // Regex to remove leading
    // zeros from a string
    String regex = "^0+(?!$)";

    // Replaces the matched
    // value with given string
    str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");

    return str;
```

but I am getting the output

```
so ow -   00250 =     00000000 ]
```

which is the same as the original input.

These methods seem to only work for the first element in the string if it is a number such as

```
00015039 so ow + - 003948 83
```

which returns

```
15039 so ow + - 003948 83
```

but want to return

```
15039 so ow + - 3948 83
```

thanks!

Comment: *These methods seem to only work for the first element in the string if it is a number*  `^0` means if the String begins with a zero, maybe you also want space followed by a zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting the given string into array and then remove the leading zeroes, is working fine.

**where removeLeadingZeros is:**

```
public static  String removeLeading(String str) {
String regex = "^0+(?!$)";
String x[] = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder();
    
for(String y:x) {
    str = y.replaceAll(regex, "");
    z.append(" " + str);
}
return z.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Arrays
.stream( input.split( " " ) )
.filter( s -> ! s.isBlank() ) 
.map(
    s -> {
        try{
            return String.valueOf( Integer.parseInt( s ) ) ; 
        } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
            return s ; 
        }
    }
)
.collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) )
```

## Split into parts, parsing each as an `int`

I would split the string into parts, delimiting by SPACE character.

```
input.split( " " )
```

Splitting results in an array. Make a stream of that array.

```java
String input = "so ow -   00250 =     00000000 ]" ;
String output = 
    Arrays
    .stream( input.split( " " ) )
…
```

All those extra spaces will result in a bunch of chunks that are empty strings, no text within. So filter those out.

And we want to eliminate whitespace as well as empty strings, so call `String#isBlank` rather than `String#isEmpty`.

```
.filter( s -> ! s.isBlank() )
```

Try to parse each part as an integer number. If the parsing fails, an exception is thrown. Trap for that exception. If caught, simply return the text that failed to parse. If no exception, return a string of the newly minted `int` value.

```java
.map(
    s -> {
        try{
            int x = Integer.parseInt( s ) ;
            return String.valueOf( x ) ; 
        } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
            return s ;  // Dismiss the exception.
        }
    }
)
```

Collect all our remaining and newly-created parts with a SPACE as their delimiter.

```
.collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) )
```

### Code example

Pulling all that code together looks like this:

```java
String input = "so ow -   00250 =     00000000 ]" ;
String output = 
    Arrays
    .stream( input.split( " " ) )
    .filter( s -> ! s.isBlank() ) 
    .map(
        s -> {
            try{
                int x = Integer.parseInt( s ) ;
                return String.valueOf( x ) ; 
            } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
                return s ;  // Swallow the exception.
            }
        }
    )
    .collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) )
;
System.out.println( output ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jv8d9x).

> so ow - 250 = 0 ]

Comment: If you split with `.stream( input.split( "\\s+" ) )` I think you would not need to do the `isBlank` filtering

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at each space character, then process each substring through your function, and then join them together again.

```
String[] substrings = myString.split(" ", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < substring.length; i++) {
    substrings[i] = removeLeadingZeros(substrings[i]);
}
myString = String.Join(" ", substrings);
```

This code is untested. I'm writing this from my phone, so I haven't been able to put it through its paces. Hopefully the general idea comes through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
String result = text.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\d[,.])(?:(0)+\\b|0+(?=[1-9]))", "$1").replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " ").trim();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jesMtp/1).

Depending on how messy your input is you might need to adjust or even expand the solution. *Details*:

- `\b(?<!\d[,.])` - a word boundary, there must be start of string or a non-word char immediately to the right, and there can be no digit + a dot or a comma immediately to the left of the current location (that is, we exclude the decimal digit matching)
- `(?:(0)+\b|0+(?=[1-9]))` - either of the two patterns:

  - `(0)+\b` - `0`, one or more times, the last `0` is saved in Group 1, followed with  a word boundary
  - `|` - or
  - `0+(?=[1-9])` - one or more `0` chars followed with a non-zero digit.

`.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " ")` shrinks any Unicode whitespace character chunks into a single ASCII space.